# how can i combine all the values of an item in other list using dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

i have two lists and need to combine the into one dictionary that the key are the letters and the values are the value in the other list.
for example:

```
map_keys_to_values_list(["a", "b", "a"], [15, 3, 6])
```

wll give me :

```
{'a': [15, 6], 'b': [3]}
```

i tried:

```
def keys_to_values_list(k_lst, v_lst):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(k_lst)):
        v=[]
        #v.append(v_lst[i])
        t = (k_lst[i],v)
        lst.append(t)
    my_dict = dict(lst)
    for k in my_dict.keys():
        val = my_dict.get(k)
        for m in range(len(k_lst)):
            val.append(v_lst[m])


    return my_dict
```

but i get all the values in my value list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def keys_to_values_list(keys, values):
    d = dict()
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        if keys[i] in d:
            d[keys[i]].append(values[i])
        else:
            d[keys[i]] = [values[i]]
    return d
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) passing the default factory as `list` to collect all the values belonging to the same character:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def map_keys_to_values_list(keys, values):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in zip(keys, values):
        d[k].append(v)
    d.default_factory = None
    return d
```

After building the dict, you can set the `default_factory` of the dict to `None` so that further key access does not produce a new list for missing keys, but instead will raise the more appropriate `KeyError`:

```
>>> d = map_keys_to_values_list(["a", "b", "a"], [15, 3, 6])
>>> d
defaultdict(None, {'a': [15, 6], 'b': [3]})
>>> d['c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'
```

Comment: Instead of setting default_factory to None, why not just calling dict(d) and returning a pure dict?

Comment: @EnricoBorba No, I wouldn't do that. That creates a new *vanilla* dict object which could be pretty expensive for large dicts. Setting `default_factory` to `None` is totally cheap as compared to `dict(d)`; `d` is already a dict subclass instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too:

```
def mapKeysToValues(keyList, valueList):
    return {k : [value for index, value in enumerate(valueList) if keyList[index]==k] for k in keyList}

keyList = ["a", "b", "a"]
valueList = [15, 3, 6]

print(mapKeysToValues(keyList, valueList))
```

Output:

```
{'a': [15, 6], 'b': [3]}
```